# Need help to understand basic Python dictionary syntax

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python and I am confused in its syntax.

I am not sure what square brackets around the variable word mean... I understand word should be our value and prev is a key.

```
mimic_dict[prev] = [word]
```

I also do not understand this expression

```
mimic_dict[prev] = mimic_dict.get(prev, []) + [word]
```

Need your help to clarify this.

I checked out documentation for python dictionary, but it was not much of help.
Sorry for such a basic question, but I really could not figure it out by googling.

Comment: You are creating a list of a single element, that happens to be `word`. The second expression says *"get the value corresponding to the key `prev`, if it doesn't exist return an empty list. Then append the element `word` to that list using list concatenation"*

Comment: 1. `[word]` is a list. 2. See [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mimic_dict[prev] = [word]
```

`[word]` is a list containing a single element, the value of the `word` variable.

```
mimic_dict.get(prev, []) + [word]
```

`+` can be used to concatenate two lists. This adds `word` to the list returned by `mimic_dict.get(prev, [])`.

And what does `mimic_dict.get(prev, [])` do? It is the same as `mimic_dict[prev]`, but if the key `prev` doesn't exist then it returns a default value of `[]` (an empty list). It ensures you always get a list back whether or not the key exists.